# fgets doesn't wait for stdin

Tags: c, input, keyboard

I'm trying to read input from `fgets()` and the function doesn't wait for output (from keyboard). We were told to use `fgets` so `scanf` is not an option here. The `fgets` function *does* work when it's used in the `main` function for some reason but not in an additional function.

Here's the code

```
char name[21]={0x0}; //tried everything; not assigning value and NULL&\0

    printf("\nName: ");

    //fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    //rewind(stdin);
    //fflush(stdin);      //these don't help
    printf(stdin);        //for testing purposes, probably pointless
    fgets(nimi, 21, stdin);
```

The program will skip the `fgets()` and not wait for input, and later adds some empty string where I want the name string. However `name` does not get the value NULL because there's an error check. I know there's quite a few people having this problem but I didn't find any help. Most people tell to use `scanf` or some other function. For the record `scanf()` will work as expected here. The syntax should be correct since it works in `main()`. I probably don't even know how `stdin` actually works so I apologise if the title is silly.

This snippet is directly after a malloc for pointer (if else clause)

Comment: _for testing purposes, probably pointless_....no, it is plain wrong....

Comment: You need to clear stdin before using fgets.

Comment: Are you using `scanf()` prior to this code? (Likely that a the problem) in addition to `printf(stdin);` is faulty.

Comment: Why the printf there? It expects a string, anything you pass will be interpreted as a string, which means you have an undefined behavior there. Remove it and it should work fine.

Comment: `stdin` is not ordinarily seekable, so `fseek()` and `rewind()` should never be used on it.  `fflush()` is for flushing *output*, not for discarding unwanted input; if, as would be typical, `stdin` is not open for writing, then the `fflush()` call will fail with an error (which you ignore).  Even if it were open for writing, flushing the output side would not serve your purpose.  In brief, don't `fflush(stdin)`, either.

Comment: Your snippet is not sufficient to explain the behavior you describe.  Construct a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, and if that exercise does not help you discover the problem for yourself then edit it into your question.

Comment: There is probably a newline still stuck in your input buffer from `scanf()`.

Comment: "*most people tell to use scanf or some other function.*". It's fine to use `fgets` here, you just have to make sure to clear the input buffer before you use it, which looks like your problem.

Answer (score 4):

People pointed out that there is something in my input buffer and that is correct. My program now works when I include

```
 while ((int ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

in my code before fgets(). There was in fact scanf functions before this. I'm eternally grateful to the guys who replied! Sorry if I made myself look like an idiot with the code. This is one of my first C programs so the code might be "a bit" off. Again thanks.